# Does the singleton pattern make sense for a Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, design-patterns

I have a Java application in which I have a socket. Now it's very important that only one socket is open at any point. I figure that a good way to ensure this is to create a wrapper class that enforces the singleton property on a `Socket` instance. For clarification: by singleton pattern I am referring to the following generic class design:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    //Private constructor prevents instantiating and subclassing
    private Singleton(){ }

    //Static 'instance' method
    public static Singleton getInstance( ) {
         return INSTANCE;
    }
    //...Other class methods
}
```

I am wondering if the idea of a singleton socket makes sense conceptually. The `Socket` will need to be able to reconnect and disconnect at any point throughout the course of the program and I'm not sure if that is possible with a singleton.

As far as I can tell this is not possible although I am hoping that there is some trick to it or I am simply misunderstanding something.

Comment: Your approach is absolutely correct.

Comment: Just for completeness, you could consider using the [enum singleton pattern](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, why not? Singleton pattern applies when you need a unique instance of a class accesible in any point of the application.

In this case, your singleton wrapper could create an instance of the socket in the constructor and expose methods to manage the socket transparently for the rest of the application.

A pseudocode example could be:

```
public class SocketDevice{

    private static final SocketDevice INSTANCE = new SocketDevice();

    private Socket socket;

    //Private constructor prevents instantiating and subclassing
    private SocketDevice(){ 
        // instanciates the socket ...
    }

    //Static 'instance' method
    public static SocketDevice getInstance( ) {
         return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void open(){
        // ...
        socket.open()
        // ...
    }

    public void close(){
        // ...
        socket.close()
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have reservations about it because the socket needs to be able to be destroyed and recreated numerous times and I was just unsure as to whether or not a singleton would be able to support this behaviour effectively. Thanks for the answer, I will have a look and get back to you :)

Comment: You're right, but singleton could handle the socket internally (create, destroy, open, whatever). 
Another approaches could be better, but this is perfectly valid. Singleton works as a wrapper that abstracts the rest of the application of the low-level management of the socket.

Comment: Maybe, the above snippet it's not a very concise example, but singleton can do anything to manage the socket internally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that this really buys you anything: indeed it may just give you a false sense of security. It doesn't stop any other part of the application from calling new Socket(...). I would just go with a Socket as an instance member somewhere.